# How to use a .py file as a module in PyCharm?

Tags: python, pycharm

I am copying analysis files to my local PyCharm to reproduce parts of it. I have a scsim.py file which runs without errors. But when I call it from another .py file as `from scsim import scsim`, it says No module named 'scsim'. Do I have to do something else to make the scsim.py file to work as a module?

[image]

Comment: I think you need to create an empty `__init__.py` file inside that `scsim` folder.

Comment: use `print(os.getcwd())` to know which folder you are running from and is used by `../../code/` as a starting directory, it's probably not what you think

Comment: also having both the folder and the file with the same name can confuse the interpreter when both folders are on your path ... this is wrong.

Comment: @Minh-LongLuu an empty __init__.py file inside scsim folder did not help.

Comment: @AhmedAEK I used print(os.getcwd()) and I am in the right folder. Renaming the directory also did not help